# Extracting string from another string in python

Tags: python, string, set, extract, unions

I have two lists

```
a = ['Shri Vatsav Ltd','Paytm Pvt ltd','Paypal ltd']
b = ['Shri Vatsav Ltd 123 HAL 2nd Stage Indiranagar Banagalore 560008','Paytm Pvt ltd 143 Jallianwallabagh Mumbai India 34567','Paypal ltd 345 Greenwood drive 123ST Long Beach CA 34566 US']
```

I need to extract only the address from list "b" using list "a" i.e, some kind of intersection or something like that. and store it as a list called  "c"

Please find the example output:

output

```
['123 HAL 2nd Stage Indiranagar Banagalore 560008','143 Jallianwallabagh Mumbai India 3456','345 Greenwood drive 123ST Long Beach CA 34566 US']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I need to extrcat only the address from string b using a

Comment: a is coming from an API response and b is my input. I want to extract only the address without company name mentioned in a. So that I can consume only address

Comment: so you want to remove the strings from list `a` where they appear in the strings in list `b` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ['Shri Vatsav Ltd', 'Paytm Pvt ltd', 'Paypal ltd']
b = ['Shri Vatsav Ltd 123 HAL 2nd Stage Indiranagar Banagalore 560008','Paytm Pvt ltd 143 Jallianwallabagh Mumbai India 34567','Paypal ltd 345 Greenwood drive 123ST Long Beach CA 34566 US']

c = [i.replace(j, "") for i in b for j in a if j in i]
print(c)  # [' 123 HAL 2nd Stage Indiranagar Banagalore 560008', ' 143 Jallianwallabagh Mumbai India 34567', ' 345 Greenwood drive 123ST Long Beach CA 34566 US']
```